# Convert SOQL milliseconds output to mm/dd/yyyy format in visualforce chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, visualforce-charting

I want to display the CreatedDate in MM/DD/YYYY format in line chart here. I am getting the SOQL output in milliseconds. I know this can be done using javascript but I am not that familiar with it.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EngagementController" >
<apex:chart height="250" width="100%" data="{!EngScore}" >
     <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="NewValue" title="Score"/>
     <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="CreatedDate" title="Date"  />
     <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" yField="NewValue" xField="CreatedDate" markerType="cross" markerSize="4"/>

</apex:chart>
```

```
public with Sharing class EngagementController {

public String currentRecordId {get;set;}

private final Account acc;
private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

public EngagementController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.acc = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    this.stdController = stdController;
   }

public List<AccountHistory>getEngScore() {
currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
return [SELECT NewValue,Field,CreatedDate From AccountHistory WHERE  AccountId = :currentRecordId AND (Field = 'Engagement_Score__c') ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];     
       }
```

}

Comment: Found this javascript ccode here:https://www.irt.org/script/919.htm but not sure how to pass value from visualforce to javascript function

Comment: $('[id$="a"]').each(function(CreatedDate){

     var text = $(CreatedDate).text();

         var milli = parseInt($(CreatedDate).text());
         var d = new Date(milli);
         var month = d.getUTCMonth()+1;
         var day = d.getUTCDate();
         var year = d.getYear().toString().slice(1);

         var newdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;                      
         $(CreatedDate).text(newdate);

         $(CreatedDate).attr('x', parseInt($(CreatedDate).attr('x')) + 30);
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard function of a class [Date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm):

> format()
>
> Returns the Date as a string using the locale of the context user

You can use wrapper class for formatting your data.

Apex:

```
public class ChartController6 {

    private Account acc;

    public ChartController6(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Data> getChartData() {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

        for (AccountHistory ah :[Select NewValue, CreatedDate From AccountHistory 
                WHERE AccountId = :acc.id and field = 'Engagement_Score__c' order by CreatedDate]){
            data.add(new Data(ah.CreatedDate.format(), Integer.valueOf(ah.NewValue)));
        }

        return data;
    }

    public class Data {
        public String closed { get; set; }
        public Integer amt { get; set; }
       
        public Data(String closed, Integer amt) {
            this.amt = amt;
            this.closed = closed;

}   }   }
```

*Since field NewValue can be anytype, it has to be converted properly*

VF:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ChartController6" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:chart height="480" width="640" data="{!ChartData}">
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="closed" 
               title="Created Date" grid="true">
               <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="amt" 
               title="New Value"/>
    <apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="closed" yField="amt" 
         markerType="circle" markerSize="0" markerFill="#8E35EF" />

</apex:chart>  
</apex:page>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: get this error:Compile Error: SObject constructor must use name=value pairs

Comment: @Mike, please find updated answer, it's using opportunity, you can modify it to use your object

Comment: getting this error now :Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].format() .Problem with the opp.closedate.format() statement

Comment: that worked. 7 blessings.